# (ionic 7 - capacitor) Sin acceso a file:///android_asset/public/assets

Tags: android, ionic, ionic-framework, capacitor

Estoy migrando una app de ionic 3 a ionic 7 y me ha servido de mucho el empezar a implementar componentes.

Ahora me encuentro con una diferencia al utilizar capacitor frente a cordova y es que hacia uso de ficheros como es una base de datos sqlite y ficheros json de configuración que copiaba en ./www/assets/.
A los que ahora no puedo acceder a fille:///android_asset/www/assets/ con el plugin FileSystem.
Y si lo hago con los componentes awesome cordova plugin FILE, no resuelve ni da error.

Espero podáis ayudarme.

Gracias.